# Python3 print, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

My code

```
for i in l:
    print (("ALTER TABLE jul ADD COLUMN %i VARCHAR(256);") %(l[i]))
```

My list

```
l=[1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]

What I got in Jupyter
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-6f78605f79c5> in <module>()
      1 for i in l:
----> 2     print (("ALTER TABLE jul ADD COLUMN %i VARCHAR(256);") %(l[i]))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: its clear that your `l` list doesn't have 1995 elements, you shouldn't need to use the index and just use it directly

Comment: it's sad how many downvotes you got, you clearly are a complete beginner on python programming and is not used to the "for in" python loop. Try to read about the "for in" python loop by yourself and you'll see what you've done. This loop iterates through all elements of your list with the variable "i" being attached to the ELEMENTS of your list and NOT their indexes. So, what you're trying to do is access l[1995] on your first iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do :

```
for i in l
```

`i` is already your element and not your index. (Also, you don't need parentheses around the string or around `i`.)

So simply do

```
for i in l:
    print ("ALTER TABLE jul ADD COLUMN %i VARCHAR(256);" % i)
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
for i in l
```

`i` will takes the values inside `l` and not its index. (i.e. i=1995, then i=1996...) Obviously the list `l` does not have that many elements

What you want is:

```
for i, li in enumerate(l):
    print(i,li)
#(0, 1995)
#(1, 1996)
#(2, 1997)
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
for i in l:
    print (("ALTER TABLE jul ADD COLUMN %i VARCHAR(256);") %(l[i]))
```

The i represents each element in the list. So the first element would be 1995 and your trying to do a l[1995] which is clearly is out or bounds.

Use

```
for i in range(len(l)):
```

or

```
for i, element in enumerate(l):
```

or just access the element i directly :

```
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Do you mean `for i, element in enumerate(l):`?